# Combining two tables together twice and then pivot in MySQL

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have been trying to solve this for a while, and I am stumped.

I have two tables, and I am basically trying to combine them and pivot them. I'm doing it in MySQL.

Here are the tables:

**pogo_dex**:

| ID | DexNum | Pokemon | Candy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Bulbasaur | Bulbasaur |
| 2 | 2 | Ivysaur | Bulbasaur |
| 3 | 3 | Venusaur | Bulbasaur |
| 4 | 4 | Charmander | Charmander |
| 5 | 5 | Charmeleon | Charmander |
| 6 | 6 | Charizard | Charmander |
| 7 | 7 | Squirtle | Squirtle |
| 8 | 8 | Wartortle | Squirtle |
| 9 | 9 | Blastoise | Squirtle |
| 10 | 10 | Caterpie | Caterpie |
| 11 | 11 | Metapod | Caterpie |

**pogo_meta**:

| ID | DexNum | Name | Form | Shadow | League | Tier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 2 | Ivysaur |  |  | Great | 3 |
| 52 | 2 | Ivysaur |  | Shadow | Great | 3 |
| 993 | 3 | Venusaur |  |  | Attackers | 7 |
| 822 | 3 | Venusaur |  |  | Master | 4 |
| 456 | 3 | Venusaur |  | Shadow | Ultra | 3 |
| 11 | 3 | Venusaur |  | Shadow | Great | 2 |
| 443 | 3 | Venusaur |  |  | Ultra | 3 |
| 804 | 3 | Venusaur |  | Shadow | Master | 4 |
| 920 | 3 | Venusaur | Mega |  | Attackers | 1 |
| 939 | 3 | Venusaur |  | Shadow | Attackers | 3 |
| 3 | 3 | Venusaur |  |  | Great | 2 |
| 964 | 6 | Charizard |  | Shadow | Attackers | 4 |
| 426 | 6 | Charizard |  | Shadow | Ultra | 2 |
| 427 | 6 | Charizard |  |  | Ultra | 2 |
| 806 | 6 | Charizard |  | Shadow | Master | 4 |
| 941 | 6 | Charizard |  | Mega X | Attackers | 3 |
| 907 | 6 | Charizard |  | Mega Y | Attackers | 0.9 |
| 97 | 6 | Charizard |  | Shadow | Great | 3 |
| 815 | 6 | Charizard |  |  | Master | 4 |
| 127 | 6 | Charizard |  |  | Great | 3 |
| 1004 | 6 | Charizard |  |  | Attackers | 7 |
| 823 | 9 | Blastoise |  |  | Master | 5 |
| 919 | 9 | Blastoise | Mega |  | Attackers | 1 |
| 104 | 9 | Blastoise |  |  | Great | 3 |
| 429 | 9 | Blastoise |  |  | Ultra | 2 |
| 328 | 12 | Butterfree |  |  | Great | 5 |
| 968 | 15 | Beedrill | Mega |  | Attackers | 4 |
| 105 | 15 | Beedrill |  |  | Great | 3 |
| 45 | 18 | Pidgeot |  |  | Great | 2 |
| 441 | 18 | Pidgeot |  |  | Ultra | 2 |

In the end, this is what I want to get out of them:

| ID | DexNum | Pokemon | Candy | Attackers | Master | Ultra | Great |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Bulbasaur | Bulbasaur | 1 | 4 | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | Ivysaur | Bulbasaur | 1 | 4 | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | 3 | Venusaur | Bulbasaur | 1 | 4 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 | Charmander | Charmander | 0.9 | 4 | 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 5 | Charmeleon | Charmander | 0.9 | 4 | 2 | 3 |
| 6 | 6 | Charizard | Charmander | 0.9 | 4 | 2 | 3 |
| 7 | 7 | Squirtle | Squirtle | 1 | 5 | 2 | 3 |
| 8 | 8 | Wartortle | Squirtle | 1 | 5 | 2 | 3 |
| 9 | 9 | Blastoise | Squirtle | 1 | 5 | 2 | 3 |
| 10 | 10 | Caterpie | Caterpie | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 |
| 11 | 11 | Metapod | Caterpie | 0 | 0 | 0 | 5 |

I know I have to left join the pogo_dex to the pogo_tiers to get the Candy associated with the Tiers. So, I wrote this:

```
SELECT b.Candy, a.League, Min(a.Tier) as Tier, a.Shadow, a.Form from `pogo_meta` a left join `pogo_dex` b on a.DexNum=b.DexNum GROUP BY b.Candy, a.League, a.Shadow, a.Form ORDER BY CAST(a.DexNum As DECIMAL) ASC
```

Then, I joined that to the rest like this:

```
SELECT c.DexNum, c.Pokemon, d.Shadow, d.Form, d.League, d.Tier FROM `pogo_dex` c LEFT JOIN (SELECT b.Candy, a.League, Min(a.Tier) as Tier, a.Shadow, a.Form from `pogo_meta` a left join `pogo_dex` b on a.DexNum=b.DexNum GROUP BY b.Candy, a.League, a.Shadow, a.Form ORDER BY CAST(a.DexNum As DECIMAL) ASC) d on c.Candy=d.Candy;
```

But now I'm stuck. How do I pivot it? I want to see the Min of each Tier for each Candy type.

Here's the Create Table for both of them:

```
CREATE TABLE `pogo_dex` (
  `ID` int NOT NULL,
  `DexNum` decimal(3,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Pokemon` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Candy` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Quantity` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `AncestorNum` varchar(4) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `AncestorName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Form` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Gender` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Item` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Special` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `pogo_meta` (
  `ID` int NOT NULL,
  `DexNum` decimal(3,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Form` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Shadow` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Tier` decimal(2,1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `League` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Both published queries select from pogo_meta - please publish sample data from this table.

Comment: @P.Salmon Whoops, that was a typo. The pogo_meta table is what I labeled pogo_tiers above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to solve it; but result_set doesn't match. I share my code and result_set here. MySQL has no pivot function; but you can use case statement to achieve a similar result.

```
SELECT c.ID, c.DexNum, c.Pokemon, c.Candy,
    MIN(case when d.League = 'Attackers' then d.Tier end) as Attackers,
    MIN(case when d.League = 'Master' then d.Tier end) as Master,
    MIN(case when d.League = 'Ultra' then d.Tier end) as Ultra,
    MIN(case when d.League = 'Great' then d.Tier end) as Great
FROM pogo_dex c
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT b.Candy, a.Tier, a.Shadow, a.League, a.Form from pogo_meta a 
left join pogo_dex b on a.DexNum=b.DexNum
GROUP BY a.DexNum, a.Tier, b.Candy, a.League, a.Shadow, a.Form
ORDER BY a.DexNum, b.Candy, a.League, a.Form 
) d 
    ON c.Candy=d.Candy
GROUP BY c.ID, c.DexNum, c.Pokemon, c.Candy;
```

Resulting query looks like this: I hope It helps somehow.

[image: Shared_screen]

Comment: This looks fine, cause even from OPs data set, `caterpie` and `metapod` seem to have null in `great`

Comment: @RinkeshP Nice to hear it, super :)

Comment: This looks great, but for some reason I am getting NULL on everything when I pop it into phpMyAdmin:
https://snipboard.io/IjKGCJ.jpg#:~:text=snipboard.io/IjKGCJ.jpg

Comment: Oh, I bet the problem is in my table. I just noticed that the Tier column is set to "varchar(45)" Hmm... I'll have to noodle that later. Can't decide if I want to change the column or just fix the query to accommodate. Gotta go play Pokémon right now! 

Comment: @Ray Hollister 

Comment: @OzanSen Thanks so much for your help. I got home from Pokemon, switched the Tier to Decimal(2,1), but still no luck.  

Weird thing happened though. _**One**_ Pokémon was showing _**one**_ league's tier. ‍♂️

The weirdest thing is, it was the _**one**_ Pokémon that I had recently edited in the pogo_meta table because it was wrong. 

So, I tried editing another Pokémon. Now that one worked. 

I looked a bit closer, and every single League has a line break after the name of the league. ‍♂️ 

Looks like I have to clean up the table a bit! Thanks again!

Comment: @RayHollister hello, I understand. where do you get the source data to insert into your database(PHP admin)?  It seems that some ETL work is necessary especially to remove those line breaks. Python is a good tool for this kind of work :)

Comment: @OzanSen I'm pretty sure it was an Excel sheet that I imported into phpMyAdmin. I just exported the SQL file, opened it in VS Code, did a search replace on "/r" and then dumped the table and re-imported it. Easy cheesy. :D

Comment: @RayHollister Fantastic 

Answer (score 0):

use alises,
your table1 AS a,
your table2 AS b

there's lack of alises initialization do it.

Comment: how does this help in getting the desired result?